# Sass has similar "avoid compilation" grammar?

Tags: sass, less

less example：

```
.class {
filter: ~"ms:alwaysHasItsOwnSyntax.For.Stuff()";
}
```

i cannot find similar in sass docment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.class
  filter: unquote("ms:alwaysHasItsOwnSyntax.For.Stuff()")
```

Works in this case.